# How to get index of triangles from poly2tri

Tags: three.js, mesh, triangulation

I will create faces for my mesh geometry based on triangles which I created wich the triangulation library **poly2tri** 
I have only a simple polygon in counter clockwise direction.
Furthermore I have no holes and steiner points only a contour!

```
 var swctx = new poly2tri.SweepContext(contour);
         swctx.triangulate();
         var triangles = swctx.getTriangles();

         triangles.forEach(function(t) {
                 t.getPoints().forEach(function (p) {
                     console.log(p.x, p.y);
                 })
         })
```

This already works for now. 
**The result:** [triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLlv3.jpg)

But the next step will be to created faces for my Mesh.geometry. And to create Face3 geometry I need the indices of my vertices.

Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
             geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(triangles[i][0],triangles[i][1],triangles[i][2]));
         }
```

How can I get the Indices out of my triangles?

Comment: If you want to use a different triangulation algorithm you could use the [three.js triangulation adapter](https://github.com/Wilt/three.js_triangulation) I created. You will be able to seamlessly connect for example *poly2tri* or *earcut* with just two lines of code.

Comment: OK I will try it. Do you have an example where I can see the source code?  I include the triangulation.js but it is written that Triangulation is an unresolved variable . Do I have to set this in the main script or in the header?

Comment: Check for an example page [here](https://rawgit.com/Wilt/three.js_triangulation/master/example.html)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for getPoint(). Based on the setup of your code example above:

```
var triangles = swctx.getTriangles();
for ( var i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++ ) {
    console.log(triangles[i].getPoint(0).x + ", " + triangles[i].getPoint(0).y);
    console.log(triangles[i].getPoint(1).x + ", " + triangles[i].getPoint(1).y);
    console.log(triangles[i].getPoint(2).x + ", " + triangles[i].getPoint(2).y);
}
```